# MassTransit with Quorum queues- Any issues?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

By default MT creates classic queue types in RabbitMQ and we are thinking to change to quorum queues( as these queue types are recommended instead of classic mirrored queues from RabbitMQ documentation) by setting x-queue-type to quorum in consumer receive endpoint configuration.

I just want to know of any issues that will come up because of this change? In MT consumer I am using “ScheduledRedelivery” using the RabbitMQ delayed plug-in so does this continue work without any issues after this change?

I just want to know, is there anything that we need to take care of with quorum queues with MT? What is your advise about changing to quorum queues?

Our set-up : RabbitMQ cluster with 3 nodes

Thanks
JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit works fine with quorum queues, just be aware of the difference.

> I don't think message time-to-live is supported with quorum queues, so they shouldn't be used for request/response in interactive scenarios. Quorum queues are also higher latency than regular queues, which would increase the response time.

#### Update

Time-to-live is supported with Quorum queues on the most recent version of RabbitMQ.

Comment: Hi Chris,

Yes I’m aware of this - I don't think message time-to-live is supported with quorum queues, so they shouldn't be used for request/response in interactive scenarios.

I am not using this as request/response but I am using scheduled redelivery using Rabbitmq delayed plug-in. Does this feature continue work with quorum queues and MT? I am guessing the scheduled redelivery uses TTL to re-queue back, so if TTL is not supported, is the scheduled delivery also not supported?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried it. The delayed exchange is an exchange (backed by Mnesia) and delivers to the queue and does not use TTL, so it shouldn't be an issue but again – I haven't tried it.

Comment: I have tested Quorum queues from MT with scheduled delivery and it worked without any issues. Thank you

Comment: Sorry if I am late  2 years... how to define the type of queue with MT?

Comment: I found it e.SetQuorumQueue();
BTW TTL on message is allowed